# How do i make changes with x input permanent?

Tags: keyboard

I need to disable my laptop keyboard and use only my usb keyboard, to do this i uses the `xinput set-prop` command, and since my keyboard id is 16, my command is `xinput set-prop 16 "Device Enabled" 0`

but when O restart my computer, i need to re-enter the command again, and this is a problem because my internal keyboard has been acting crazy, how do save this changes??

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways of doing this. If you're absolutely sure the ID never changes, the easiest may be to put the line into Systems->Preferences->Startup Applications.

The canonical method seems to be editing udev rules nowadays. There's a Wiki page on this [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input).

Answer (score 1):

Edit the X.org configuration file located in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` . It handles input devices as well as displays

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of doing this is by appending `xinput set-prop 16 "Device Enabled" 0` to  `~/.xprofile`